# Indexing lines and substituting values between them based on multiline replacement

Tags: python

I have a file text file with following characters list:
chars = ['carl', 'charles', 'gary']

1st)

```
face person eyes 01 mouth 05 brows 00 blush 00 tears 00
person"Lovely" id person_0fc83b3b
```

2nd)

```
person "Lovely!" id person_0ac83b4b
```

The expected substitution would be to append the, "id person_0fc83b3b" as "id face_0fc83b3b" to the previous line.

For the second, the output would be a new line, "face person blank id face_0fc83b3b" followed by the text line with the person id in it.

So for the first output:

```
face person eyes 01 mouth 05 brows 00 blush 00 tears 00 id face_0fc83b3b
person "Lovely" id person_0fc83b3b
```

And for the second output:

```
face person blank id face_0ac83b4b
person "Lovely!" id person_0ac83b4b
```

I am trying the following python code:

```
chars = ['carl', 'charles', 'gary']
with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
new_lines = []
for line in lines:
    for char in chars:
        if char in line:
            if 'face ' + char + " eye" in line:
                line = line.strip() + ' id face_' + line.split()[-1].strip() + '\n'
            elif char + ' "' in line:
                new_lines.append('face ' + char + ' blank id face_' + line.split()[-1].strip() + '\n')
     new_lines.append(line)
 with open('modified.txt', 'w') as f:
     f.writelines(new_lines)
```

However, I am getting:

```
face person eyes 01 mouth 05 brows 00 blush 00 tears 00 id face_00
face person blank id face_person_8fc08b3b
    person "Lovely" id person_0fc83b3b
```

and

```
face person blank id face_person_0ac83b4b
    person "Lovely!" id person_0ac83b4b
```

The second one is correct, minus missing the same indentation.  The first should have appended as mentioned previously.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the line:

```
line = line.strip() + ' id face_' + line.split()[-1].strip() + '\n'
```

Here, `line.split()[-1].strip()` is retrieving `person_0fc83b3b` instead of `0fc83b3b`. To get the correct substring, you can replace the line with:

```
line = line.strip() + ' id face_' + line.split()[-1].strip().split("_")[-1] + '\n'
```